# I'm trying to extract reviews inside the i-frame using selenium in python but not able to access inner HTML.?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract reviews from iframe and I'm trying to switch into the iframe and i guess i successfully switched, but not able to access further tags and attributes..

I have tried multiple solution which is comment, I need to get specific review div or even if we get full page source of iframe then I'm able to parse via Beautifulsoup.

Url=https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000295971597.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.46754f9bCFP2xJ&s=p&ad_pvid=202005070358123970448424509400000207120_1&algo_pvid=28913e75-ad10-4d7c-a25b-e1c67d3e18be&algo_expid=28913e75-ad10-4d7c-a25b-e1c67d3e18be-0&btsid=0ab6d69f15888490922438266e45ea&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

My code:

```
from telnetlib import EC
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def get_pro_reviews():
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(web_url)
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]'))).click()
    print('==> Review tab Clicked')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(200, 1200)")
    sleep(5)
except Exception as error:
    product['Review'] = 'Reviews Not available'
    print(f'Error in Clicking review tab ==>{error}')
try:
    sleep(5)
    # driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    # iframes=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    # chn=driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
    print(driver)
    che = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-evaluation']")))
    print('==> Swithched to iframe')
    print(che)
    print(driver)
    review_elem = driver.page_source()
    # review_elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.feedback-list-wrap')
    print(review_elem)
    # review_elem = chn.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[5]')
    review_elem_source_code = review_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    review_elem_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(review_elem_source_code, 'html.parser')
    print(review_elem_soup)

    for review_raw in review_elem_soup.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.feedback-item'):
        print(review_raw)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
except Exception as error:
    print(f'Error in getting Reviews ==>{error}')
```

Error:

```
Error in getting Reviews ==>'str' object is not callable
```

These are the Reviews required me!

[image]

Comment: can you put a picture of what content do you which to retrieve?

Comment: @Armando yes let me put!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added **web_url** variable at the top because was not defined.

I added **product** as a **dict** at the top because was not defined. I assume is a dict because you do `product['Review'] = 'Reviews Not available'`. If you have it defined in another place, remove both.

Now, we will take a look at your mistakes:

```
review_elem = driver.page_source()
```

**Mistakes:**

1)page_source is a property not a method of the class so you should remove **()**

2) This will return a string containing all the html so that is why you get the error:

`"Error in getting Reviews ==>'str' object is not callable"`

str because review_elem is a string at this moment and is not callable because you can not call a property ( the `()` ), you just access it as a attribute of the class.

After understanding this concept, this will not work for you. If you continue and run the code as you have it you will get another error when assigning this:

`review_elem_source_code = review_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

because review_elem (which is a string) does not have the method `get_attribute()`.
So, I prorpose the following:

```
review_elem_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
```

This will get the innerHtml of the iframe.

Finally, after doing this you will get another error because of the following mistake in the for loop:

```
review_elem_soup.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.feedback-item')
```

`find_elements_by_css_selector()` does not exist in BeautifulSoup this exist in the driver. So, in order to get all the elements you want with BeautifulSoup you should change to this:

```
review_elem_soup.select('div.feedback-item')
```

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

web_url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000295971597.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.46754f9bCFP2xJ&s=p&ad_pvid=202005070358123970448424509400000207120_1&algo_pvid=28913e75-ad10-4d7c-a25b-e1c67d3e18be&algo_expid=28913e75-ad10-4d7c-a25b-e1c67d3e18be-0&btsid=0ab6d69f15888490922438266e45ea&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(web_url)
product = {}
try:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]'))).click()
    print('==> Review tab Clicked')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(200, 1200)")
    sleep(5)
except Exception as error:
    product['Review'] = 'Reviews Not available'
    print(f'Error in Clicking review tab ==>{error}')
try:
    sleep(5)
    che = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-evaluation']")))
    print('==> Switched to iframe')
    review_elem_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
    review_elem_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(review_elem_source_code, 'html.parser')
    for review_raw in review_elem_soup.select('div.feedback-item'):
        print(review_raw)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
except Exception as error:
    print(f'Error in getting Reviews ==>{error}')
```

Ps: I remove most of your prints so code is easier to explain.

Hope this help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @mobin alhassan Sorry I was a little busy. I could not reply before hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks It's working perfect for me...That was intentionally to not define that variable, I assume you understand.